# How To Save Results Of A Nested Loop Separately For Each Unique Combination In R

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-loops

How do I save results of my nested loop and save separately in to my lists?

My `data` looks likes this:

```
> data
  id factor
1  1      A
2  2      B
3  1      A
```

Then I make an empty vector of 4 lists since there are 2 unique values for `id` and 2 for `factor`

```
data <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 2, 1), "factor" = c("A", "B", "A"))

empty <- vector(mode = "list", length = 4)
for(i in seq_along(unique(data$id))){
  for (j in seq_along(unique(data$factor))) {
    empty[[i*j]] <- data %>%
      filter(id == unique(id)[i] & factor == unique(factor)[j])
  }
}
empty[[1]]

> empty[[1]]
  id factor
1  1      A
2  1      A

> empty[[2]]
[1] id     factor
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

`empty[[1]]` works, but from `empty[[2]]` to `empty[[3]]` gives me an empty list. I guess I am messed up with the`empty[[i*j]]` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by using `expand.grid` to create a data frame with all unique combinations of your variables in `data`, then running a simpler `for` loop over a sequence representing the rows in that data frame. So:

```
combos <- with(data, expand.grid(id = unique(id), factor = unique(factor)))

empty <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(combos))

for (i in seq(nrow(combos))) {

  empty[[i]] <- filter(data, id == combos$id[i] & factor == combos$factor[i])

}
```

That produces this list:

```
> empty
[[1]]
  id factor
1  1      A
2  1      A

[[2]]
[1] id     factor
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[3]]
[1] id     factor
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[4]]
  id factor
1  2      B
```

If you want to leave the slots for the empty sets as `NULL`, you could put the filtering step inside an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because you don't have any samples for `empty[[2]]` and `empty[[3]]` since those corresponds to `1 B` and `2 A`, and you should get

```r
  id factor
1  2      B
```

for `empty[[4]]`.

Comment: Oh, right since 2*1 equals 1*2. Then how do I write a nested for loop that saves the results for all combinations ?

Comment: I don't get the question? You already have the list called `empty` and some of its elements are empty and some of them are not.